# How to get the event source from calling element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an event listener in a list item :

```
        <li class="item" ng-click="click($event)">
            <a href="#/home">Home</a>
        </li>
```

In my controller I have a click handler :

```
 $scope.click = function($event) {      
        t2 = $($event.target.parentElement);
        t2.addClass('clicked');
}
```

However, sometimes my **$event.target** is the list element, and sometimes it is the anchor element. This is because of where I click, sometimes it is on the a element but not on the list. Is there a way of getting from the event object the element that *called the function*?

Comment: Use $event.currentTarget

Comment: perfect thanks. can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $event.currentTarget

```
 $scope.click = function($event) {      
    t2 = $($event.currentTarget.parentElement);
    t2.addClass('clicked');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with the DOM inside controllers.  Use directives instead.

According to [Angular JS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

> Do not use controllers to:
>
> - Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.

```
$scope.selectedId = null;

$scope.clickFn = function(e) {
    $scope.selectedId = e.currentTarget;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-class="{ 'clicked-class-name' : selectedId === 'someId' }" id="someId" ng-click="clickFn($event)">
```